# Qpid Variant type to handle byte arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, variant, qpid

I'm working on a project and I need to be able to send byte arrays through Qpid, but Variant has no idea what an array is. Is there some way, I can convert the byte array into something Variant, like maybe a Variant::list of unit8, or a Variant::string, then when I get the response, I can convert the string or list back into a byte[]?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `qpid::types::Variant::List`. Convert all of your bytes (I assume you're using `unsigned char`) to `uint8_t` and then append them to the list.

Example:

```
unsigned char bytesToSend[] = {104, 101, 108, 108, 111}; /* "hello" */
int lengthOfArray = sizeof(bytesToSend)/sizeof(byteToSend[0]);
qpid::types::Variant::List lstToSend;
for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++){
    uint8_t thisByte = (uint8_t)bytesToSend[i];
    lstToSend.push_back(qpid::types::Variant(thisByte));
}
qpid::messaging::Message msg;
qpid::messaging::encode(lstToSend, msg);
yourSender.send(msg, false); /* change false to true if you want to sync with the broker. */
```

I have not tested this, but it should provide a general overview.

If you have further questions, feel free to ask and I'll try to answer them as best as I can.

---

References:

- [Sender.send method](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.30/messaging-api/cpp/api/classqpid_1_1messaging_1_1Sender.html#adedcff9ec995b301479d395f995736a9)
- [Variant Documentation](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.30/messaging-api/cpp/api/classqpid_1_1types_1_1Variant.html)
- [Encode(list, message) method](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.30/messaging-api/cpp/api/namespaceqpid_1_1messaging.html#a55dd99067ddd06c285c44dca46c683f3)
- [Red Hat - QPID Maps and Lists in C++](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Programming_in_Apache_Qpid/sect-Programming_in_Apache_Qpid-Maps_and_Lists_in_Message_Content-Qpid_Maps_and_Lists_in_C.html)
- [Receive This C++ List in C#](http://grokbase.com/t/qpid/users/12ap9jhe3c/how-would-you-receive-this-c-list-in-c#201210237raamjze7pacbtzphyztaf0vym)
- [Maps and Lists in Message Content](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.14/books/Programming-In-Apache-Qpid/html/ch02s11.html) **Slightly outdated, but still has good information**